# Problem Lasso-ElasticNet and hyper alpha-Lambda grid search

Tags: r, statistics, prediction

EDIT : The error seems to be related with the range of values for Lambda. This range  10^seq(-5,-1,length=100) doesnt produce the error but this range seq(-2,5,length=100) does.The 2ond range(the error one) is more fitted for the data.

I am trying to use Ridge - Lasso - Elastic Net to compare which method performs better in predicting US "Real.GDP.Growth". I use RMSE to compare the model performance.
I have a dataset with Y("Real.GDP.Growth") and 36 X(independent variables). Dimensions of the data are 125x37.
Problem : Ridge works without an error. Lasso and elastic net give me this error :

```
    In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
      There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

From reading online i think the reason is that some tuning parameter combination produces predictions that are constant for all samples. train() tries to compute the R^2 and, since it needs a non-zero variance, it produces an NA for that statistic.

How do i solve that? I still get results but they are weird and the variable importance plot doesnt work. I plan to make a grid like this `alpha =seq(0,1,0.01)` for Enet and `lambda =seq(0,1,0.01)` for lasso-Enet.
I tried to include the data with dput but i exceed the character limit. What other way do i have to show you the data?
Code is below:

```
    #TRAIN-TEST
set.seed(240884)
train_rows <- sample(1:dim(dataUS)[1], .805*dim(dataUS)[1])
US.train <- as.data.frame(dataUS[train_rows,])
US.test <- as.data.frame(dataUS[-train_rows,])

library(glmnet)
library(Metrics)
library(caret)


#Custom CV rule
custom <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 10,
                       repeats = 5,
                       verboseIter = F)



# Ridge Regression
set.seed(1234)
ridge <- train(Real.GDP.Growth~. ,US.train, method="glmnet",trControl=custom,tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0,lambda = seq(0.001,20,by = 0.1)))
ridge.predicted <- predict(ridge, s=ridge$lambda.1se, newx=as.matrix(US.test[,2:37]))
rmse(US.test[,1],ridge.predicted)
# Plot Results
plot(ridge)
plot(ridge$finalModel, xvar = "lambda", label = T)
plot(ridge$finalModel, xvar = 'dev', label=T)
plot(varImp(ridge, scale=T))


# Lasso Regression
set.seed(1234)
lasso <- train(Real.GDP.Growth~. , US.train , method="glmnet",trControl=custom,tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1,lambda = seq(0.01,1,by = 0.01)))
lasso.predicted <- predict(lasso, s=lasso$lambda.1se, newx=as.matrix(US.test[,2:37]))
rmse(US.test[,1],lasso.predicted)
# Plot Results
plot(lasso)
plot(lasso$finalModel, xvar = 'lambda', label=T)
plot(varImp(lasso, scale=T))


# Elastic Net Regression
set.seed(1234)
en <- train(Real.GDP.Growth~. , US.train , method="glmnet",trControl=custom,tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha =seq(0,1,0.05),lambda = seq(0.3,0.9,by = 0.1)))
Enet.predicted <- predict(en, s=en$lambda.1se, newx=as.matrix(US.test[,2:37]))
rmse(US.test[,1],Enet.predicted)
# Plot Results
plot(en)
plot(en$finalModel, xvar = 'lambda', label=T)
plot(en$finalModel, xvar = 'dev', label=T)
plot(varImp(en))

rmse(US.test[,1],alpha0.predicted);rmse(US.test[,1],lasso.predicted);rmse(US.test[,1],Enet.predicted)


# Compare Models
model_list <- list(Ridge=ridge,Lasso=lasso,ElasticNet=en)
res <- resamples(model_list)
summary(res)

# Best Model
ridge$bestTune
lasso$bestTune
en$bestTune
best <- en$finalModel
coef(best, s = en$bestTune$lambda)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Even if you cannot share your data, please include some example data so others can see what is going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.